# Can't lookup ENS name on testnet of an address

Tags: ethers.js, ens, goerli

I'm trying to create an app that works with ENS. I tried registering a test domain on Georli network. Here's the link when I lookup that test domain on app.ens.domains.

https://app.ens.domains/name/rikikudo6.test/details

I try using `ethers` to resolve ens domain as well as looking up a specific address. Here's the code I'm using:

```
var ethers = require("ethers");
// I use rpc endpoint generated by alchemy on Georli network
var provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpc);

(async () => {
    var address = await provider.resolveName("rikikudo6.test");
    console.log("address :>> ", address);

    const ens = await provider.lookupAddress(address);
    console.log("ens :>> ", ens);
})();
```

And here's the result when I run the above script:

```
address :>>  0x8A2D9D8e54FF47d28Cc35Aa2ba244d49F14944cA
ens :>>  null
```

I don't understand why it can resolve the name for `rikikudo6.test` but can't lookup ens for the address returned by the resolving function. Am I missing anything?